# React get JavaScript Object from JSON file?

Tags: json, reactjs

The issue is that I'm trying to get a **JavaScript** object like the following:

```
[
    "id" : 11,
    "name" : "Peter"
    "other": {
          "id": 22,
          "item": 534
    },
    "main": false
]
```

Since I want to get this via reactjs: I trying to do this:

```
  http.get(API.BASE_URL + API.USER_INFO)
    .accept('Application/json')
    .end((err, res) => {
        //console.log(x);
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
    });
```

When I try a normal json string I get the right result, but with this javascript object I get:

```
Error: Parser is unable to parse the response
undefined
```

Has anyone come across this before? Any idea?

Comment: Downvotes there is something call comments....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to parse isn't valid JSON (as well as JavaScript) because you've written it out as an array, but still use key/value pairs as if it were an object. Try this instead:

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Peter",
    "other": {
        "id": 22,
        "item": 534
    },
    "main": false
}
```